# how can I connect Nord vpn in ubuntu in vps without fail?

Tags: vpn

when with terminal connected successfully to nordvpn, vps failed and I should reset vps. how can I connect Nord vpn in ubuntu in vps without fail?

Comment: Connecting "without fail" is a logical impossibility. If you had specified the error you get to lead you to the "vps failed" message, maybe we could help you with that.

Comment: please tell me how can I enable vpn support in ubuntu. there is way to to prevent vps from out or fail. some people said there is a way to enable it(vpn) in ubuntu. I just want know that way

Comment: Does no one know this? very strange!